# Place Order Error

Tags: magento2, orders

When I place an order, I got this error message:

```
An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.
```

I catched it via log and it was:

```
INVALID_REQUEST: Field [order.avsDetails.billToFirstname] was not in charset [ISO-8859-1]
```

Please help.

Comment: What's the name that you are using? Is on checkout or admin panel? Are you using a third-party module on checkout?

Comment: I am using Arabic name and it is in checkout. yes I am using this extension for VISA/Master `https://marketplace.magento.com/ontap-module-mastercard.html`. I am trying to solve it in vain.

Comment: Please check error log as well

Comment: I checked it more and more. it throws `INVALID_REQUEST: Field [order.avsDetails.billToFirstname] was not in charset [ISO-8859-1]`

Comment: Kindly, Can you have a look on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184272/create-custom-avatar-attribute-on-registration-page?