# Create custom avatar attribute on registration page

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-attribute

How can I add customer image as an avatar to be shown in customer profile.
So user can add his image from registration page.

Comment: @vishwas, Do you have a solution ??

Comment: Please reefer to this https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-customer-attribute-programmatically.html  , you create a custom attribute for image upload like this the above  tutorial

Comment: Build according to the above script , share the code here if you stuck anywhere then i can help

Comment: Here is the code, please check it.. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186036/sign-up-with-avatar-rest-api-validation-error-magento-2?noredirect=1#comment257219_186036