# Sign Up With Avatar REST API Validation Error : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I have this code for image attribute (avatar).

**app/code/Ibnab/CustomerPut/Setup/InstallData.php :**

```
<?php
namespace Ibnab\CustomerPut\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;





class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "avatar");

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "avatar",  array(
            "type"     => "varchar",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "Avatar",
            "input"    => "image",
            "source"   => "",
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => true,
            "default" => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"     => false,
            "note"       => ""

        ));

        $avatar   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "avatar");

        $avatar = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'avatar');
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $avatar->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100);

        $avatar->save();

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**app/code/Ibnab/CustomerPut/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customerput" template="Ibnab_CustomerPut::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Ibnab/CustomerPut/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
         <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  template="Ibnab_CustomerPut::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
         </referenceContainer>

        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Ibnab/CustomerPut/view/frontend/templates/additionalinfocustomer.phtml**

```
   <fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend><br>

        <div class="field avatar required">
            <label for="avatar" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Avatar') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Avatar') ?>" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

- Avatar is shown perfectly in registration page and i can upload an image easily. But I am trying to sign up using rest API as :

  **POST http://localhost/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/customers**

  ```
   customer[email]​ = abc@gmail.com 
   customer[firstname]​ = abc
   customer[lastname]​ = xyz 
   password​ = abc@12345 
   avatar   ms.jpg       =>(file)
  ```

but I am always get message :

```
{
    "message": "\"Avatar\" is a required value."
}
```

[image]

Please help ..

Comment: Have you tried implementing avatar as a custom or extension attribute? See here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html

Comment: I implemented it as a custom attribute in a custom extension as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the new attribute configuration.

You create this attribute with required to true :

```
"required" => true,
```

I do not think that you can make this attribute not required only for REST.

But I think that you can make it required on the store scope.

If you want to make it required with the API, you need to create/update the API endpoint in order to be able to upload this file. Maybe by sending the file encoded in base64 but carefull with security issue.

Comment: @Frank, Thank you. I tried to make the attribute not required. but it posted the data and didn't upload the image. I think my error is in the avatar attribute:   {
     "customer": {
         "email": "abc@gmail.com",
         "firstname": "Abc",
         "lastname": "Xyz" ,
         "custom_attributes": [
       {
         "attribute_code": "avatar",
         "value": ""
       }
     ]

     },
      
     "password": "Abc@123456"
     
  } ,, How can I encode image ? because the result is {
    "message": "The image content must be valid base64 encoded data."