# Retreive ALL Product details in Search REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Dears, I am using this API in search:

**GET** `http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/search`

**Parameters**:

```
searchCriteria[requestName]= quick_search_container
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field] = search_term
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value] = life
```

But I always retrieve products results without image as:

> {"items":[{"id":211,"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"score","value":"91.9732208251953100"}]},{"id":483,"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"score","value":"91.9732208251953100"}]},{"id":46,"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"score","value":"91.9732208251953100"}]},{"id":50,"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"score","value":"91.9732208251953100"}]},{"id":40,"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"score","value":"5.7483263015747070"}]},{"id":41,"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"score","value":"5.7483263015747070"}]},{"id":45,"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"score","value":"5.7483263015747070"}]}],"aggregations":{"buckets":[{"name":"category_bucket","values":[{"value":"3","metrics":["3","2"]},{"value":"6","metrics":["6","2"]},{"value":"7","metrics":["7","1"]},{"value":"8","metrics":["8","1"]},{"value":"9","metrics":["9","3"]},{"value":"10","metrics":["10","3"]},{"value":"12","metrics":["12","2"]},{"value":"15","metrics":["15","1"]},{"value":"16","metrics":["16","1"]}]}],"bucket_names":["category_bucket"]},"search_criteria":{"request_name":"quick_search_container","filter_groups":[{"filters":[{"field":"search_term","value":"life","condition_type":"eq"}]}]},"total_count":7}

How can I retrieve product details included images ?

Comment: have you get any feasible solution ??

Comment: Do it as custom API

Comment: please provide any reference if any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform a fulltext search, the native API you used returns only the product IDs (from the search engine : Mysql or ElasticSearch) that match the search term.

Two approaches :

1. Do another API calls in order to have product details based on the IDs returned (not perfect for performance)
2. Create your own API based on this search API in order to load the product collection based on the product IDs retrieved.

It is feasible but need code customization.

Internally, Magento uses this search API request, then store the result in a temp table in order to load the product collection in a second time to display product listing in frontend sorted by score.

Comment: @Frank, Thank you. It is bad design to call another API to get product details. Can you please check this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186036/sign-up-with-avatar-rest-api-validation-error-magento-2?noredirect=1#comment257219_186036 ?

Comment: Yes, it is recommended to create your own API endpoint and manage the logic inside to format the response based on your search term. I did it on my project by creating a custom ElasticSearch request then loading the product collection filtering by product IDs returned. The best but the hard is to store all your information in ElasticSearch and then retrieve information only from ElasticSearch without Magento SQL requests.